# how to use tessdata_best for tesseract (pytesseract). What are the arguments and procedure?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract, tesseract.js

**TL;DR: How do I install `tessdata_best` to use with`pytesseract` inside `conda` in `Ubuntu 18`**?

I have been using `pytesseract` inside `conda` environment for quite some but there is a need to improve the accuracy and I found out that `tessdata_best` gives you the best accuracy. How can I install and use that version? I am using `Ubuntu 18` and have to work with `pytesseract`.

I have my `tesseract` installed at `/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/` and inside it there is only 1 `tessdata`.

**Do I need to get the `tessdata_best` from github by copying it to the directory `/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/` alongside `tessdata`?**

Even then, if I want to use `tessdata-best`, what do I have to use? Do I need to change the `config` as  `--oem 0/1/2/3`?

Third and last thing is that I have my `language.trainedata` files at `/home/deshwal/anaconda3/envs/py36/share/tessdata/eng.traineddata`. Do I need to paste the `tessdata_best` at this location too? Becuse when I try to change the language dir, it gives me error as as:

`/home/deshwal/anaconda3/envs/py36/share/tessdata/equ.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language \'equ\' Tesseract couldn\'t load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.'`

Comment: If you have found an answer, please let me know. If you have not, try to look into re-training Tesseract on new images -- it's quite a learning curve, but I think it will be worth it in the end. 
Best of luck!

Comment: Have you found an answer? I want to use the tessdata_best but I don't know how.

Comment: @captaincustard No luck at all till now

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of pytesseract, you can use `config` argument with `--tessdata-dir`, as follows :

```
# Example config: r'--tessdata-dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata"'
# It's important to add double quotes around the dir path.
tessdata_dir_config = r'--tessdata-dir "<replace_with_your_tessdata_dir_path>"'
pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='chi_sim', config=tessdata_dir_config)
```

For more details see https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I understand your question clearly, however let me know if below helps ...
You need to set datapath with location where you will copy the tessdata_best training models, For example,

Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();  // JNA Interface Mapping
tesseract.setDatapath("/home/tesseract/tessdata_best_4_0_0/tessdata");

All your .traineddata files which you downloaded from (https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_best) should be placed in the directory you define in setDataPath (for example:, /home/tesseract/tessdata_best_4_0_0/tessdata).

Please note: These models only work with the LSTM OCR engine of Tesseract 4 so make sure you have used library 4.1 or above.

Regards,
Maulik